# Cannot locate button web element with xpath using selenium

Tags: scala, selenium, xpath

In the website I want to automate the there is a button I want to click on, if you inspect the element of the button it looks like this:

```
<input type="submit" value="Login" class="submit">
```

So I click on this line any then do "Copy xpath" and copy it to my code like this:

```
val loginButton: WebElement = driver.findElement(By.xpath("""//*[@id="loginForm"]/fieldset/font/font/input """))


loginButton.click()
```

Its very weird cause in other places it worked perfectly and sometimes I have problems with it, and then I try by cssSelector but here nothing works :/

Comment: Why Extra ''"" added in Xpath ?

Comment: @RupeshShinde otherwise intellij cant read it, you have to add it so it will see it as a complete string

Comment: @RupeshShinde it's a triple-quoted string literal in Scala, so it can include double quote characters (in the predicate) without needing to backslash-escape them.

Comment: Is the `input` element _always_ in two layers of `font`?  Maybe a more general path like `//*[@id="loginForm"]//input[@type="submit"]` would be more robust.

Comment: @IanRoberts you were right, please add this as an answer and ill mark it

Comment: @IanRoberts but why when I do just the chrome function "copy xpath" i get this and not what you corrected?

Comment: There are many different XPath expressions that will select the same element, Chrome has given you one of them, I suggested another. Essentially the Chrome suggestion says "find an input inside a font inside a font inside the form" whereas mine says "find a submit button inside the form" - two different descriptions of the same target element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The path includes two layers of `font` elements which seems rather fragile to me - any slight changes to the page structure will mean this path fails to match.

I would try a path that considers just the "semantics" of which element you want to target, and not the precise structure of the page. You want the submit button in the login form, so how about a path like

```
//*[@id="loginForm"]//input[@type="submit"]
```

which finds *any* `<input type="submit">` anywhere in the form. If there are several submit buttons you can be more specific with `@type="submit" and @value="Login"`

Answer (score 0):

XPath is prone to break and IMHO overly complicated... I would use a CSS Selector.

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input.submit")).click();
```

This is Java, BTW, but hopefully you can translate it, if needed.